# AudioTrack. How can I use sessionId?

Tags: android, audio

Documentations says: sessionId - Id of audio session the AudioTrack must be attached to

May I use it something like this?:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test);
            mp.start();

int minSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(
        44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, 
        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT );

    at = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 
                        44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, 
                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minSize, 
                        AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM, mp.getAudioSessionId());

    at.setStereoVolume(0.0f, 1.0f);
```

What is right way to connect audio track to stream which used to media player. Can I make changes on this stream using AudioTrack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to specify a session ID, as there's also an [AudioTrack constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html#AudioTrack%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) that doesn't have a sessionId input parameter. However, as the documentation states, if you want to **"associate audio effects to a particular instance of AudioTrack"** you should use the constructor that takes a session ID.
This session ID can either be taken from a MediaPlayer instance that you have created - or it can be zero, in which case **"a new session will be created for this track if none is supplied"**.

Comment: Now there is only 1 undeprecated constructor (API >= 26). `AudioTrack` has 3 constructors. 2 of 3 are deprecated. So there is only one which needs `sessionId`

Answer (score 0):

While looking through the [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.Builder), I found an `AudioTrack.Builder` class. A snippet of the documentaiton explains that

> If the session ID is not specified with setSessionId(int), a new one will be generated.

It appears that this method would allow for creation of a new AudioTrack without need of supplying a session ID.